# Finding the general formula for Dn

Tags: linear-algebra

Given D(n+1) =(a+b)D(n) -abD(n-1) for all n>=2
How do i find the general formula for Dn?

I already created 2 equations.

Dn     =    1Dn         0
Dn+1 = (a+b)Dn   -abDn-1

I found the eigenvalues 1 , -ab and corresponding eigenvectors, ((1+ab)/a+b),1), (0,1))

But now iam stuck and iam not sure what to do next

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
D_n= \alpha a^n + \beta b^n.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

For the recurrence equation$$D_{n+1} =(a+b)D_n -abD_{n-1}$$ the characteristic equation is
$$r^2=(a+b)r-ab$$ Solve the quadratic to get the roots $r_1$ and $r_2$ and use
$$D_n=c_1 \,r_1^n+c_2\, r_2^n$$